# WebKitErrorDomain while integrating facebook ios sdk in my ios application. Using Dialog Feed to post on wall

Tags: ios, facebook, integration

I m using facebook ios sdk from github, for integrating facebook in my iPhone application. I m trying to share something in the wall. When I click share, it goes to facebook, does single sign on login, and comes back to my application. After coming to my application, it should show a webview with share options which was already there in FBDialog.m file. But, instead of showing this, it is dismissing automatically with webview didfail with error with error "WebKitErrorDomain" with error code = 102.

They have handled it by catching it up and dismissing the webview, but how to resolve it? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out when this webkiterrordomain occurs. If the parameters you send to Facebook dialog feed are incorrect it stops you loading the UIWebView throwing error called WebkitErrorDomain. Check your parameters, you will solve it.